# check the validation of selecting the cell from each section

Tags: ios

I need to check in each section.

I have questions in the header of the section .And the options in the cellfor row in tableview .After selecting the cells.I have Submit button .So while clicking the submit button it should validate whether i have selected a cell from each section .How to do.

For that my current code is as below:-

```
let totalSections = questionViewModel.numberOfSections()
        for section in 0..<totalSections {
            let totalRows = questionViewModel.numberOfRowsIn(section:section)

            for row in 0..<totalRows{

                let cell = self.tableview.cellForRow(at: NSIndexPath(row: row, section: section) as IndexPath)

              //  self.tableview.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: row, section: section))


                print("Section: \(section)  Row: \(row)")

                let model = questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: IndexPath(row: row, section: section))
                print(model.isSelected)

                           // questionViewModel.search(indexPath: IndexPath(row: row, section: section))

                questionViewModel.search(indexPath: IndexPath(row: row, section: section))
                print(questionViewModel.OptionListArray)

                if (questionViewModel.OptionListArray?.count)!>=1{
                    print("success")
                    continue
                }
                else{
                    let questionModel = questionViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atsection: section)
                                                        print(questionModel.question)

                                                        let controller = UIAlertController(title: "Please Select any option from question", message:(questionModel.question), preferredStyle: .alert)
                                                        // Create the actions
                                                        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
                                                            UIAlertAction in
                                                            NSLog("OK Pressed")
                                                            self.viewDidLoad()

                                                        }
                                                        controller.addAction(okAction)
                                                        //  controller.addAction(cancel)

                                                        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)

                                                       // self.viewDidLoad()

                }

               }


         }
```

i am doing in mvvm .So my viewmodel as below:-

```
var OptionListArray:Array<NH_OptionsModel>? = []
  func search(indexPath: IndexPath)-> Bool {

     OptionListArray =  (datasourceModel.dataListArray?[indexPath.section].optionsModelArray.filter{($0.isSelected! == true)})!

      print(OptionListArray)

      return true

     }
```

So i need the following output.
If i have selected one cell from each section then go for the button action .Else if any of the cell is not selected then show the alert for selecting option for particular section.How to do.

Here i already set as isSelected as false initial for model.While I selecting the cell it become true.

So for that i have filter whether for each section did any model has isSelected = true.If not display alert to select any option fro section number.How to implement

Comment: how to validation at each section?

Comment: Iterate over your selected rows, putting the section for each selected row in a set. Check the count if the set. If it is less than the number of sections then there is a section without a selection. It isn't clear what problem you are having with your current code; what happens? What do you want to happen?

Comment: @Paulw11 can u show how to implement?